# LoadImage() with variable path?

Tags: c, winapi

How do I get `LoadImage();` to work with a variable file path? I have the desired file path in the variable `bg`, and I'm calling the function like so:
`bmp = LoadImage(hInst,bg,IMAGE_BITMAP,640,480,LR_LOADFROMFILE);`

Yet `bmp` does not render any image when used with:  `BitBlt(hDC,0,0,640,480,memDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);`

---

If I can't use `LoadImage();`, what equivalent is there that can handle non-constant file names?

---

[EDIT]

Apparently, the error was caused by another bit of code, and not the LoadImage() function. Disragerd.

Comment: What is `bg[]` when `LoadImage(hInst,bg,IMAGE_BITMAP...` called?  There is no call to `md0()` to populate it.

Comment: Does the application crash, or does your image simply not show up? Are you sure that your timer is firing properly?

Comment: If you want to find out what is wrong with your program you should debug it. Why do programmers if today no longer debug their programs?

Comment: Your `WM_PAINT` is leaking memory (you are not restoring the `HBITMAP` that `SelectObject()` replaced. You have to call `SelectObject()` again before calling `DeleteDC()`), and using `PostMessage()` to trigger a paint handler is wrong. Use `InvalidateRect()` instead, and let the OS trigger `WM_PAINT` when it is ready to do so.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Code that is deliberately hard to read (like the indirect function calls through function pointers) is not very helpful.

Comment: You made your question to short! The suggestion was to make minimal + **complete** + **verifiable** example. That does NOT mean make the question "as short as possible". Nobody would have guessed your problem from those 2 lines. By the way, you don't have to specify width and height, you can just use `LoadImage(hInst,bg,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the timer. The documentation about the [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) function says that the second parameter (`nIDEvent`) must be a **nonzero** value. So, I imagine your timer is never firing, the `execmain()` function is never called, and so your `bg` string is never set.

When you replace `bg` by a string literal, it works, because the `WM_PAINT` message does not depend on the timer, it is always called at least once when the window is created.

Comment: I set the timer ID to 1001, but it still doesn't work. What else could I try?

Comment: Did you already try to use `InvalidateRect()` instead of sending a `WM_PAINT` message manually?

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks!